# How much would it cost to launch a 0.5U Satellite?

Tags: launch, low-earth-orbit, cubesat

I have seen the figures for 1U, 3U and 12U Satellites such as those provided [here](https://spaceflight.com/pricing/), but I have been unable to find pricing for the launch of a single 0.5U or 0.25U satellite.

I have seen many academic and industry satellites of this size, and I was wondering how they get into orbit. Do they need to be transported and deployed from a 3U like Swarm Technologies does?

Specifically, if I wanted to send only my 0.25U Satellite to Space without coordinating with 11 other 1/4U's to fill a 3U, is there even a provider that would do this?

Assume for the question of pricing, I want to get to LEO.

Thank you!

Comment: [SpaceBEEs](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacebee) are 1/4 U satellites and have been launched [seven times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swarm_Technologies) There might be some information from those. See also [How does the SpaceBEEs' experimental passive radar reflector work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25979/12102) for details and [Are the SpaceBEEs still “illegal” or did they eventually receive approval to operate?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40591/12102)

Comment: Some smallsats are deployed from the ISS. If you only have 1 0.25U satellite, perhaps that would be a better option? In that ase I assume the price would be some tens of thousands of dollars (cargo space + astronauts deploying your satellite). Otherwise, I would imagine you will have to come up with a way to fit into a standardized launcher.

Comment: @uhoh, I mentioned Swarm Technologies in my post. They are the company that made the Space Bee 0.25 U's. The pack 12 into a 3U to reduce costs since they launch at volume. I was specifically asking for the price for a single 0.25U CubeSat

Comment: @codeosaur yep, my comment is for the benefit of any potential *future reader* who would like to read further about sub-1U cubesats, and doing so also add those to the "linked" section at the right https://i.stack.imgur.com/z47r7.png